# how to Delete where multiple columns IN\NOT IN other table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a target Table and a source table

and I want to delete a row from it only if some of the column's data appear in another table (the source table)

for example:

Target Table to delete from it:

```
|  Delivery  |   Order     |     Row      |  OtherColumn |
|:----------:|:-----------:|:------------:|:------------:|
|     1      |     A       |    000010    |     asaf     |
|     1      |     A       |    000020    |     ag       |
|     2      |     C       |    000010    |     DEL      |<-I WANT TO DELETE THIS ROW
|     2      |     D       |    000020    |     hhs      |  
|     3      |     E       |    000040    |     ba       |
|     3      |     E       |    000170    |     ass      |
```

Source table, Here I have a row that i want to KEEP in the target table :

```
|  Delivery  |   Order     |     Row      |
|:----------:|:-----------:|:------------:|
|     2      |     D       |    000020    |
```

the result I'm looking for the target table is:

```
|  Delivery  |   Order     |     Row      |  OtherColumn |
|:----------:|:-----------:|:------------:|:------------:|
|     1      |     A       |    000010    |     asaf     |
|     1      |     A       |    000020    |     ag       |
|     2      |     D       |    000020    |     hhs      |  
|     3      |     E       |    000040    |     ba       |
|     3      |     E       |    000170    |     ass      |
```

Meaning, all the rows for delivery number 2 would be deleted **if they are not in the source table**

I have the Delivery parameter as @Delivery

what I tried is:

```
delete from Target 
where Delivery = @Delivery
and ([Delivery],[Order],[Row]) not in (select [Delivery],[Order],[Row] 
                                 from Source)
```

but there's a syntax error, I understand multiple columns are not acceptable in NOT IN operator,

what can i do?

Comment: The operator you are looking for is `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: `IN` only accepts a single scalar expression on both sides of the operator. Consider using `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use NOT EXISTS:

```
delete from Target 
from Target target
where Delivery = @Delivery
and NOT EXISTS (select 1 from Source s where s.[Delivery] = target.Delivery and 
    s.[Order] = target.[Order] and s.[Row] = target.[Row] )
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the below query.

```
DELETE from Target WHERE Delivery = @Delivery AND NOT EXists(SELECT 1 from Source 
WHERE Delivery =Target.Delivery AND Order=Target.Order and Row=Target.Row )
```